# How to check file(pdf) write protection?

Tags: files

What is the simplest way to check if file(pdf) got write protection(or not got)?

I am using Ubuntu and not got any solution.

Comment: Is this a question about PDF _encrypton_, or are you just asking how to check whether a _file is write-protected_?

Comment: whether a file is write-protected only.

Comment: Which operating system?  Command line or API?  If API, which language?

Comment: command line or ubuntu gui, or web check, does not metter. Simpler seems to check in file properties.

Comment: What is the context related to  sqa/testing? Better question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is somehow required by some clinets to have file without or with write protection. So it is a way to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use from command line ls -l.  This lists files in a directory and shows the permissions for the files.  The permissions look something like this:
-rw-r--r--. 1 user1   users
It belongs in this case to the group users and user1 is the owner of the file.  The -rw means that the owner has read/write, the group has read and the overall permission for the file is read (anyone outside the group).

More info about understanding permissions in linux: http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

Comment: Seems like the simplest so good. Still I am not sure if pdf not got other locks and how to change them, but I guess it is not that crucial. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [bash script](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) to check if a file is writable. Bash is the default shell under Ubuntu.

Example script from: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-scripting-test-if-filewritable/

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"

[ $# -eq 0 ] && exit 1

if [ -w "$FILE" ]
then
   echo "Write permission is granted on $FILE"
else
   echo "Write permission is NOT granted on $FILE"
fi
```

This checks if the file is writable for the current user running the script.